# How can i move a gtk window from a workspace to another using wnck in python?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, wnck

i'm trying to develop a python application that allow to move windows between gnome workspace. I' m using wnck to interact with windows, but i'd like to know how can i move a window from a workspace to another. Anyone can suggests me a way?

I tried with following code

```
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
window_list = screen.get_windows()
titlePattern = re.compile('.*Downloads.*')
    if len(window_list) == 0:
        print "No Windows Found"
    for win in window_list:
        if(titlePattern.match(win.get_name())):
            win.move_to_workspace(screen.get_workspace(2))
```

but screen.get_workspace(2) return 'None', while it works (but it doesn't move the window!) if i use screen.get_workspace(0) as move_to_workspace parameter.

Can i solve my problem?

Thank you in advance to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window manager simply doesn't have workspace 2 when you call `screen.get_workspace(2)`.

Your code should work for all workspaces that actually exist. In GNOME 3 that means all workspaces that already have windows plus one empty workspace. This means that `screen.get_workspace(screen.get_workspace_count() - 1)` should give you the "empty" workspace, if that was what you were looking for. Note that there's no spec that says the last workspace is empy, it's just what gnome-shell currently happens to do.

You can also ask the window manager to increase the number of workspaces on the screen, but it is under no obligation to do so: the GNOME 3 window manager will not do it.

Oh, and one thing to remember about Wnck:

> At its creation, a WnckScreen object will not have fetched information
>   from the X server. If queried immediately after its creation (via
>   wnck_screen_get_windows() or wnck_screen_get_workspaces(), for
>   example), the WnckScreen object will look like there are no workspaces
>   nor windows on the screen. This information is fetched in the main
>   event loop with an idle source, to avoid an expensive synchronous
>   operation on startup. If no main event loop is used, or if the
>   information is needed as soon as possible after the creation of the
>   object, wnck_screen_force_update() can be used to explicitly fetch the
>   information.

I don't think this is your problem (as you have a list of windows already), but I'm just double-checking as it's a nasty pitfall.

Comment: thank you @jku. so i can't move my windows in an empty workspace? I'm working on gnome classic envorinment.

Comment: There's nothing that stops you from moving windows to an empty workspace, but the workspace must exist. In normal GNOME 3 there is always one empty workspace (the last one) but I have no idea what the classic mode does.

Comment: i have 4 workspace in my environment (i jump between their with ctrl+alt+arrows). maybe I'm misunderstanding the meaning of 'workspace'?

Comment: You've probably understood it as well as it's possible... The whole thing is just not very clearly specified, and different implementations end up doing very different things. Still, if screen.get_workspace(2) is None, that _should_ mean that only a maximum of 2 workspaces currently exist (0 and 1). You could do a `screen.get_workspaces()` and  print `workspace.get_number()` for each workspace to check that.